# Cannot find a way to negate a regexp inside the pattern

Tags: mysql, regex

I can't find a way to use the regexp to find all matches that contains the **first word** and **the second** word but between the two **should not** be a specific word.

`select '<p>66-155</p><p>en application</p>' regexp '66-155.*[<,p,>]en application'`

**should return 0**

`select '<p>66-155 en application</p>' regexp '66-155.*[<,p,>]en application'`

**should return 1**

Comment: Try `select '<p>66-155</p><p>en application</p>' LIKE '%66-155%en application%' AND NOT LIKE '%66-155%<p>%en application%'`. What is your MySQL version?

Comment: In MySQL versions before 8.0, you cannot use a single regex for that since it is a POSIX based regex that does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please give me sometime to try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL versions before 8.0, you cannot use a single regex for that since it is a POSIX based regex that does not support lookarounds.

With earlier versions of MySQL, you could use something like

```
LIKE '%66-155%en application%' AND NOT LIKE '%66-155%<p>%en application%'
```

If, instead of literal substrings, you have regex patterns, then it would look like

```
REGEXP '66-155.*en application' AND NOT REGEXP '66-155.*<p>.*en application'
```

In MySQL 8.x, with the ICU regex engine, you may use a lookaround based regex:

```
REGEXP '66-155(?:(?!<p>).)*?en application'
```

The `(?:(?!<p>).)*?` is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) that matches any char (other than a line break char, to match any char including line breaks, add `(?s)` at the pattern start) with `.`, as few repetitions as possible (due to `*?` quantifier), that does not start a `<p>` char sequence.